# Why $\int_{\mathbb R^n}e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \, dx_1\cdots dx_n=\omega_{n-1}\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2}r^{n-1} \, dr$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\omega_{n-1}$ the area of the surface of the sphere in $\mathbb R^n$, i.e. 
the surface of the set
$\mathcal S=\left\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mid \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2=1\right\}.$

We know that the area of the sphere of radius $r$ is $r^{n-1}\omega_{n-1}$. Why does it imply that
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n}e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \, dx_1\cdots dx_n=\omega_{n-1}\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2}r^{n-1} \,dr\text{ ?}$$

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 = r^2$, so this is just the usual polar substitution after integrating out the angular variables.

Comment: Did you mean that $\omega_{n-1}$  is the area of surface rather than $\omega_{n-1}$ be the surface?

Comment: ok thanks :-) @Math_overview: yes :-)

Comment: Did you mean that $\sum_{i=1}^1 x_i^2=1$ rather than $\sum_{i=1}^1 x_i=1$ ?

Comment: it's more $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$ but yes :-)